# Why can't I pipe ffmpeg output fed from webcam?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, webcam

I am trying to capture the input of my webcam and pipe the stdout of ffmpeg to another process.

The command I am using is `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "0" -` and it keeps giving me the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x7fc7ea81da00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

If I replace - with a filename video gets recorded properly, but I can't seem to pipe it anywhere. Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: You need to add the `-f` output option to choose an appropriate output format, but without more info from you I can't give a specific suggestion.

Comment: I've never used `ffmpeg` before so I don't have much to say as I'm just experimenting. All I'm trying to do right now is pipe data from my webcam to a nodejs process and start working from there. All research I did would do the same thing with files and 'just adding - at the end sends everything to `stdout`' but it just doesn't work like that

Comment: Ok right after posting this comment I tried adding `-f matroska` right before the `-` character and it worked. Didn't know that the same argument can be used multiple times :)